# Converting between MongoDB.Bson versions

Tags: c#, mongodb-.net-driver, bson, bsondocument

I have an application writing BsonDocuments created by MongoDB C# driver (v1.10.xxx) as byte array to RabbitMQ. Then I have another application which was using the same driver to read and convert the byte representation of the BsonDocument back to it's object form.

Then, I needed to upgrade the MongoDB C# driver to version 2.3, now I can't read back the bytes waiting in RabbitMQ queue back to `BsonDocument`, the structure remains but the values are gone.

Does anyone have an idea for that?

The code responsible for writing to RabbitMQ:

```cs
BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    bf.Serialize(ms, prm_xBsonDocument);
    lock (m_xChannelMessageTrace)
    {
        m_xChannelMessageTrace.QueueBind(m_strQueueNameMessageTrace, m_strExchangeNameCommunication, prm_TraceType.ToString(), null);
        m_xChannelMessageTrace.BasicPublish(m_strExchangeNameCommunication, prm_TraceType.ToString(), null, ms.ToArray());
    }
}
```

For reading I use:

```
var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer((IModel)property);
consumer.Received += (model, ea) =>
{
    var ms = new MemoryStream(ea.Body);
 
    try
    {
        var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        BsonDocument xBsonDocument = ((BsonDocument)formatter.Deserialize(ms));
```

Writer app MongoDB C# driver version: `v1.10.0.62`

Reader app MongoDB C# driver version: `v2.3.0.157`

The RabbitMQ record starts like:

> \0\0\0\0����\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\f\0\0\0QMongoDB.Bson, Version=1.10.0.62, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f686731cfb9cc103\0\0\0MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument\0\0\0\t_elements\b_indexes_allowDuplicateNamesBsonValue+*bsonType\0�System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[MongoDB.Bson.BsonElement, MongoDB.Bson, Version=1.10.0.62, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f686731cfb9cc103]]�System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]MongoDB.Bson.BsonType\0\0\0\0\0\0\t\0\0\0\t\0\0\0\0����MongoDB.Bson.BsonType\0\0\0\avalue*_\0\b\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0�System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[MongoDB.Bson.BsonElement, MongoDB.Bson, Version=1.10.0.62, Culture=neutral,...